# How to get the values of all selected options in select tags named skill[]?

Tags: javascript, css

Having the following html structure

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <button>Add item</button>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <button>Delete</button>

        <div>
            <label>Skill</label>

            <select name="skills[]">
                <option value="one" selected="">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Level</label>

            <select name="levels[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <button>Delete</button>

        <div>
            <label>Skill</label>

            <select name="skills[]">
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two" selected="">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Level</label>

            <select name="levels[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <button>Delete</button>

        <div>
            <label>Skill</label>

            <select name="skills[]">
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three" selected="">three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Level</label>

            <select name="levels[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get a list of values of all selected options in select tags named skill[].

I am expecting the result `['one', 'two', 'three']`

In order to accomplish this I am first trying:

```
document.querySelector('#container').querySelectorAll('select[name=skills[]]')
```

I get the following error message

`SyntaxError: 'select[name=components[]]' is not a valid selector`

I also think I could try to get all first `select` tag in every `div.well` tag

```
document.querySelector('#container').querySelectorAll('.well > select:first-child')
```

But I am getting a empty NodeList

Thanks for any suggestions to solve this scenario

Thanks for any advice

---

Thanks everyone I got the answer thanks to you comments and answers.

This give me the values of all selected options in select tags named skill[]

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="skills[]"] option:checked')).map(option => option.value)
```

This prints `['one', 'two', 'three']`

Comment: Do you mean `...querySelectorAll('select[name=skills[]:first]')`?

Comment: @clearshot66 the asker didn't tagged jQuery, if possible, provide a vanilla JS solution

Comment: No, he means [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/). Non jQuery solution is `document.querySelector(selector)`. Always returns the first match only of the CSS selector `selector`.

Comment: Sorry but I can not use jquery

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're looking for. I included a snippet that will console log the variable whenever a `skills[]` select box is changed.

`document.querySelectorAll('[name="skills[]"] option:checked')`

```js
let selectionArray = []

document.querySelectorAll('[name="skills[]"]').forEach(menu => {
  menu.addEventListener('change', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const selection = document.querySelectorAll('[name="skills[]"] option:checked')  
    selection.forEach((selected, i) => {
      selectionArray[i] = selected.value
    })
    console.log(selectionArray)
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <button>Add item</button>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <button>Delete</button>

        <div>
            <label>Skill</label>

            <select name="skills[]">
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Level</label>

            <select name="levels[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <button>Delete</button>

        <div>
            <label>Skill</label>

            <select name="skills[]">
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Level</label>

            <select name="levels[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <button>Delete</button>

        <div>
            <label>Skill</label>

            <select name="skills[]">
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Level</label>

            <select name="levels[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the question to better explain my intention

Comment: Gotcha, updating my answer now

Comment: @user615274 just realized you wanted the values in the array. Updated the snippet to log the array whenever you make a selection from a `skills[]` menu.

Answer (score 0):

*How to get the first select tag in a set of divs?*

In vanilla JS, use `document.querySelector('select[name="skills[]"]');` if you want to select the first element with matching selector.

`document.querySelector` always returns the first element with matching selector. and `document.querySelectorAll` gives the node list i-e all of the nodes that match the selector

```js
var el = document.querySelector('select[name="skills[]"]');

console.log(el.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <button>Add item</button>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <button>Delete</button>

        <div>
            <label>Skill</label>

            <select name="skills[]">
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Level</label>

            <select name="levels[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <button>Delete</button>

        <div>
            <label>Skill</label>

            <select name="skills[]">
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Level</label>

            <select name="levels[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <button>Delete</button>

        <div>
            <label>Skill</label>

            <select name="skills[]">
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Level</label>

            <select name="levels[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the question to better explain my intention